# Meaning of vector mass

Tags: particle-physics

I hear the phrase vector mass being used a lot in discussions of various models in particle physics.

But I am not exactly sure what it means.

There is no Wikipedia article on this term. Is vector mass somehow different from scalar mass?

The only possible mass terms in the Lagrangian arise due to quadratic self-interactions and interactions between different fields. In this respect, we have a scalar mass and a mass matrix respectively.

But what exactly is a vector mass?

**Edit to question:**

My question in in relation to the use of the word 'vector mass' in the article https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06320. The word 'vector mass' is used to describe the masses in expression $1.1$ of the article.

Comment: https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:13700731. has a reference,  but I have no idea if it is correct or not.

Comment: Not very helpful.

Comment: Sorry about that......I was basing my attempts to source for you  on your original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is that you are confused and are actually hearing about massive scalar particles and massive vector particles, rather than the term "scalar mass" or "vector mass" itself, although the context in which you heard these terms might clarify the situation and cast light on some other meaning in a particular context.

I could also imagine that someone might use the term "scalar mass" to refer to mass arising from interactions with the scalar Higgs field, and "vector mass" to refer to mass arising from gluon fields which are carried by vector mesons, although I have never heard that usage myself.

Another possibility is that someone may be trying to distinguish between the energy and momentum components of [invariant mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass) ($m_{0}$) which is defined as follows:

$m_{0}^{2}c^{2}=\left({\frac {E}{c}}\right)^{2}-\left\|\mathbf {p} \right\|^{2}$

Someone could be calling the energy component "scalar mass" and the momentum component "vector mass", since energy is a scalar quantity (it is defined by a single number) and momentum is a vector quantity (it has both magnitude and direction). Once again, however, I have never personally heard that usage employed.

Another context in which the term "vector mass" is used in some articles is to refer to the mass of a vector boson.

UPDATED BASED ON CLARIFICATION OF QUESTION:

And the winner is, none of the above. Based on the context stated in the clarified question, vector mass is referring to something described in [this Physics Stack post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166590/running-of-the-higgs-mu-term-or-running-of-individual-mass-terms-in-a-complica). This states in the pertinent part:

> I am interested in calculating the (one-loop) beta function for a
>   'vector mass' in a SUSY model. By vector mass, I mean something like
>   μQμQ in a superpotential term
>
> μQQ¯QμQQ¯Q,
>
> where Q,Q¯Q,Q¯ are superfields in the fundamental and conjugate
>   representations of the gauge group, respectively. This is obviously
>   completely analogous to the supersymmetric Higgs mass term
>
> μHuHdμHuHd.
>
> Like the Higgs μμ term in the MSSM, in this model the μQμQ term will
>   be found in combination with other mass terms in the relevant mass
>   matrices. For instance, eq. 8.1.2 in Martin's A Supersymmetry Primer
>   (http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9709356) shows the coefficients of the
>   quadratic terms of the scalar fields H0u,H0dHu0,Hd0 are combinations
>   of μ,m2Hu,m2Hd,b,g,g′μ,mHu2,mHd2,b,g,g′. And then there are the
>   Higgsino mass matrices (or neutralino and chargino mass matrices, more
>   accurately, of which the Higgsinos are part), in which it also
>   appears.
>
> In my model, the fact that the μQμQ term is found in combination with
>   other mass terms follows from the existence of other terms in the
>   superpotential, like the Yukawa term
>
> yuQU¯HuyuQU¯Hu,
>
> as well as from soft SUSY breaking terms.

In simple terms, it is a generalization of the mass that arises from a Higgs Yukawa, although I have no idea why one would call this a "vector mass". Perhaps someone else at stack exchange can clarify that linguistic leap.

END UPDATE

**Scalar Bosons**

A scalar particle is a boson with [total angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_angular_momentum_quantum_number) (commonly called "spin") of 0, that is not pseudo-scalar (i.e. it has even rather than odd parity). (The spin of a particle is basically a symmetry that relates to how much rotation a particle must experience to act in the same way as it did prior to rotation.) A scalar particle may in principle be either massive or massless, but in practice, all known scalar bosons are massive. If Newtonian gravity had been carried by a boson and propagated at the speed of light rather than instantaneously, it would have been carried by a massless fundamental scalar boson (but, of course, Newtonian gravity is actually just a rough approximation of general relativity and so there are no such bosons).

The only known fundamental scalar boson is the [Higgs boson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson) with a mass of about 125 GeV$/c^{2}$.

There are two [scalar mesons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_meson) with irregular proper names: K0*(800) or kappa, f0(500) or sigma. The former has a mass of about 800 MeV$/c^{2}$ an the latter has a mass of about 500 MeV$/c^{2}$. The others scalar mesons are represented by symbols indicating their general type and mass, but do not have irregular names as many of the lighter pseudoscalar and vector mesons do. The internal structure of scalar mesons is a matter of ongoing debate in the [quantum chromodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics) (QCD) community of physicists.

There are many massive, composite [pseudo-scalar mesons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mesons), the lightest of which is the pion which has a mass of roughly 140 MeV$/c^{2}$, which plays an important part in carrying the residual strong force that binds protons and neutrons in atomic nuclei. The residual strong force fields that bind protons and neutrons do make a contribution to the mass of the atoms of the atomic nuclei that they bind (which could conceivably be called "pseudo-scalar mass" or could be abbreviated to "scalar mass").

**Vector Bosons**

A vector particle is a boson with spin 1 (depending on its parity it may be either a true vector boson or an axial vector boson). Vector bosons can be fundamental or composite, and may be massive or massless.

The massless fundamental vector bosons are the photon (which carries the electromagnetic force) and the gluon (which carried the strong force).

The massive fundamental vector bosons are the W+ boson, the W- boson and the Z boson, all of which are associated with the weak force. The W boson mass is about 80.4 GeV$/c^{2}$ and the Z boson mass is about 91.2 GeV$/c^{2}$.

There are also a great many [vector mesons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mesons), which are composite bosons bound by the strong force. Some of the better known vector mesons are the charged and neutral rho mesons (each of which has a mass of about 775 MeV$/c^{2}$), the omega meson (which has a mass of about 783 MeV$/c^{2}$), and the phi meson (which has a mass of about 1019 MeV$/c^{2}$). The first three involve various combinations of up and down valence quarks and antiquarks. The phi meson has a strange quark and an antistrange quark as valence quarks.

**Tensor Bosons**

For completeness, if a boson has spin-2 it is called a tensor boson. There is one widely hypothesized fundamental massless tensor boson, the graviton. There are a variety of massive tensor mesons which are composite bosons bound by the strong force, most of which are usually thought of as excited states of lower spin bosons.

**In General**

All of these particles obey the [Bose-Einstein statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_statistics) which is why they are called bosons. Indeed, all particles with integer spin are bosons.

The mass of the massive fundamental bosons and the mass of the fundamental fermions (at least the quarks and charged leptons anyway, we're not entirely sure where the mass of the neutrinos comes from) arises from the coupling of the fundamental particle in question to the Higgs field.

The mass of the composite mesons arises in part from a combination of the mass of the quarks in those mesons that arises from the Higgs field, and in part from the mass-energy of the gluon fields that bind those quarks which could arguably be called "vector mass". In mesons composed of light quarks (up, down and strange), most of the mass comes from the gluon field. In mesons composed of heavy quarks (charm and bottom), most of the mass comes from the valence quarks in the meson.

Comment: +1 great answer, I was going to tell the OP about the mass related to vector bosons,  but it seems the post has been since edited to reflect knowledge of that, I learnt a lot from your comprehensive answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A vector mass is referred to the mass the wave has. A particle has ascalar (longitudinal) mass and the wave has a vector mass such that $\vec{m} c=m_0\vec{v}$, where c is the speed of light.
Read the full article at
https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.03200